# MySQL TRIGGER : Delete or Update from table 2 after delete from table 1

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two table :

Table 1

| Book's Name | Publications |
| --- | --- |
| Poem | A |
| Novel | A |
| Math | B |

and Table 2

| Publications | Number of Books |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |

Now, I want to write a trigger that after deleting from Table 1 and Number of books = 0 , delete that row from table 2 and if Number of books not null update the value of the Number of books.

**for Example** :

**1.delete from Table 1
where Bookname=poem**

and

**2.delete from Table 1
where Bookname=Math**

Then Table 2 would be change like This

| Publications | Number of Books |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |

Comment: I advice you have a view instead of  `Table 2`.

Comment: **Design error!** Why keep that count when you can get it dynamically from a `select count(*) from books where publications = 'A'` or even get all using a GROUP BY. This ways its Always going to be accurate.

Comment: Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but the two commenters are correct, I would use a view instead of a table for Table 2. For example:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwTable2
AS
    SELECT Publications, COUNT(*) BooksNumber
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Publications
```

If it has to be a trigger this should do the trick. It's a bit hacky but that's the price you gotta pay when you want to solve a problem one way. I wrote this in mssql though so might need a bit of converting to mysql as I'm not well versed in it.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trUpdateTable2 ON dbo.Table1
AFTER INSERT
    ,UPDATE
    ,DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Table2

    INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
    SELECT Publications, COUNT(*) BooksNumber
    FROM dbo.Table1
    GROUP BY Publications

END;
```

Comment: It was useful and help me, Thanks a lot